# RxJS wait for all ajax requests in a stream

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have the below code where I am calling first one API to get a set of data and based on that data I am calling another API where I get another set of data. The second api call (and the data I ultimately want to recieve) is called x times where x is the number of entries in the array from the first API call.

My question is if it is possible for the observable sequence to wait for all API calls to repoTwo to be complete and then return the data as one array rather than one array per request.

I can work around it by concatenating the results in a temporary array and when the complete calback is invoked, I have all the data, but should it not be possible to do in the observable sequence alone?

```
let concat: Array<RepoTwoData> = [];
this.repoOne
    .get()
    .flatMap((value: Array<RepoOneData>) => {
        return Observable.from(value);
    })
    .flatMap((value: RepoOneData) => {
        return this.repoTwo.get(value);
    })
    .subscribe((next: Array<RepoTwoData>) => {
        concat = concat.concat(next);
    }, () => {/* */}, () => {
        this.handleConcatData(concat);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`toArray`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/toarray.md) operator. This takes all the elements of your stream and put it into one single array, as soon as the stream completes. So if your elements are arrays, you will get an array of arrays.

```
this.repoOne
    .get()
    .flatMap((value: Array<RepoOneData>) => {
        return Observable.from(value);
    })
    .flatMap((value: RepoOneData) => {
        return this.repoTwo.get(value);
    })
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(arrayOfRetrievedValues => ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is an ok solution, not exacly what I wanted but it is close enough. I can add a .map operator after the .toArray, to handle concatnating the arrays and output it as one.